# MIPS: takes an address to a letter, determines the upper case version of that letter, and stores it back into the same memory location

Tags: assembly, mips

So basically, given a string, we will convert any occurences of lowercase to uppercase and store the address of the uppercase to the same memory location of the lowercase address. Im still new in this MIPS assembly language and very confused if im doing this right. Also why do we have to allocate space for the string? i tried removing it and the it outputs the same? so im confused how does allocating space differs from not allocating any space? Here is my code so far:

```
STR_str: .asciiz "Test String"
to_upper:       
    li $t0, 0               # Set t0 = 0

upper_loop:
    lb $t1, STR_str($t0)    # Load byte from 't0'th position into $t1
    beq $t1, 0, exit        # If it ends then exits the loop
    blt $t1, 'a', case      # If less than a, exit
    bgt $t1, 'z', case      # If greater than z, exit
    sub $t1, $t1, 32        # If lowercase, then subtract 32
    sb $t1, STR_str($t0)    # Store it back to 't0'th position in the string

case: 
    addi $t0, $t0, 1        # if not lower, then increment $t0 and continue
    j upper_loop

exit:
    jr  $ra                 # Return to caller
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a `syscall` to actually read user input. Assuming that's what you want. If you are given the string already, then you don't need the first 3 instructions. You allocated the space elsewhere that you did not show, namely at the `STR_str` definition. Otherwise the code looks okay.

Comment: ```STR_str:
 .asciiz "Hunden, Katten, Glassen" ``` this is the given string. actually this is just a subroutine.

Comment: If you put a label somewhere and don't reserve any bytes for stuff there, whatever comes next will have the same address.  But if there is nothing next, memory protection usually works in 4k pages, so the CPU won't actually fault if you access memory past the end of your `.data` section's reservations unless you go that far past.  i.e. there's sort of an implicit `.space` out to the next multiple of 4096 bytes at the end of the .data section.

Comment: The code shown looks ok, so problems seem to be in code not shown.  Use the debugger, single step through it to see what's going on.